# Jumping through text file if certain condition is not met vb.net

Tags: vb.net, text

I want to know if there is a way to read a text file that lets say has content like so:

Store - 001P \n
Owner - Greg \n
Price - 45000 \n
Employees - 30 \n

Store - 002\n
Owner- Jen \n
Price - 34400 \n

Now lets say I only want to work with the store information in the block where the store number contains a P. Is there a way to read the text file to check for the P after the delimiter, and then skip to the next instance of "store" in the text file? I tried to find which function is best as in different languages you can GoTo function, but I cannot find anything on this.

This is a snippet of my current code:

```
Dim columnV As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)   
    Dim descriptionV As String
    Dim quantityV As Integer

    For Each totalLine As String In MyData
    descriptionV  = Split(totalLine, "-")(0)
    quantityV = Split(totalLine, "-")(1)
        If columnV.ContainsKey(descriptionV) Then
            columnV(descriptionV) = colSums(descriptionV) + quantityV
        Else
            columnV.Add(descriptionV, quantityV)
        End If
    'Next
```

Comment: Depending on size, might be easier to just read the entire file into memory as either a string list or datatable, then skipping around records should be a whole heap simplier

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean with 'GoTo' in other languages? With text all you can do is manually read through the lines, there's no magic to skip lines (if a function seems to do that, it's just doing it in the background without telling you)

Comment: Yep, so I am reading the entire file in my code, but I need to quantify the numbers under a specific store number, so if this store number doesnt qualify I would like to skip the batch. So currently I am putting all the read values in a dictionary with one column being the value before the delimiter and one after the delimiter, if that makes sense.

Comment: You probably don't need `GoTo` for this.  You probably just want to set a flag temporarily, and when set, skip ahead to the next line that has "Store".